# Do we have a Joomla component which can zip many components and install them

Tags: joomla

Do we have a Joomla component which can zip many components and install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Joomla! Package Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/installers/3779) will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Not so far...

Would be a great timesaver though

Comment: I maintain a site on local host which is basically blank but set up with all the components modules and plugins installed (lets call it basesite ).
When I need a new site I copy folder in htdocs and rename (newsite)

I then do a search for basesite and replace with newsite in configuration.php.

Finally I go into Phpmyadmin and duplicate database (which I named basesite when setting up originally and name the new database newsite.

If you use a lot of extensions it can save a lot of time.

Realize this was not question...but still may be helpful